# Movie about a mad scientist stealing life/talent/enthusiasm from unsuspecting teen girl or girls. Black guy hero

Tags: story-identification, science

It was an older movie, probably 80's-ish era. Medium budget. Scientist was trying to defy the aging process. Girls he used were young teens, and the process killed them, I think.

I only caught the end, when the hero, a black guy, was trying to stop the scientist from draining the youth and/or special talents of a very attractive, rather young-looking teen girl who was lying unconscious on an elevated table with kind of psychedelic images on the machine's monitors along with the typical flashing lights and fancy dials/switches everywhere. The black guy was flabbergasted and appalled by what he saw and tried to talk some sense to the scientist, who was not receptive whatsoever. The dialogue was incredible, and I think music was somehow involved with the plot.

This could have been a 70's or possibly even a late 60's flick, but I saw it within the last 5 years. I live in Northern California and had Comcast at the time.

Please help, it's driving me bonkers! Thanks very much. - Seth

Answer (score 3):

"[Vampires](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0178965/?ref_=rvi_tt)"(1986)?

It did star an African-American actor, Duane Jones, famous star of "Night of the Living Dead"(1968). The year was a bit later than what you described, but here is a plot description from IMDb which seems to match.

> The students at a private art school are unaware that the school's headmistress is secretly using a machine to extract the life energy from young girls there.

And here is a plot synopsis from the 1st user review:

> "Vampires" is a low budget Vampire-Horror movie settled around a university somewhere in the States. There, an ever-young director draws suspicion when more and more of her students die or disappear. As time passes, we learn that her husband once made a powerful invention that stops aging itself and now his wife is on a hunt to collect the positive souls she needs to stay alive and well.

I can't seem to upload any pictures and this one has a very generic title, but it was released on DVD from Film Chest?

Also, the other thing that makes me think this is it is the fact that you thought music was a factor in the plot. The user reviews made mention of the heavy synthesizer score.